# tabs not displayed in camera slideshow slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating a brands slideshow that displays all related brands to a specific category, I'm using pixedelic camera slider and the problem is that the slider is working as standalone but when implementing it in my main page the tabs are not displayed this is the css for the inner div:

```
.brandImg{
        min-width:717px;
        max-width:1332px;
        width:100%;
        }
    .brandImg img{
        width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:relative;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
        }
        .brandImg div{
            width:20%;
            height:30%;
            background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
            float:left;
            margin:2%;
            margin-top:0.5%;
            margin-bottom:0.5%;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:contain;
            background-position:center;
            }
        .brandImg div:hover{
            cursor:pointer;
            }
```

this is the php/html file:

```
 <div class="fluid_container" >
    <div class="camera_wrap camera_emboss pattern_1" id="camera_wrap_4" >


        <div  data-src="images/transparent.png">
            <div class="brandImg">
                <?php for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){?>
                    <div style="background-image:url('images/brands/<?php echo $rowbrands[0][2]?>/<?php echo $rowbrandscat[0][1]?><?php if($_GET['section']!=0){echo '/'.$rowbrandsubcat[0][2];}?>/<?php echo $rowimage[$i][3];?>')"></div>
                <?php }?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if($cimage>12){?>
        <div  data-src="images/transparent.png">
            <div class="brandImg">
                <?php for($i=12;$i<$cimage;$i++){?>
                    <div style="background-image:url('images/brands/<?php echo $rowbrands[0][2]?>/<?php echo $rowbrandscat[0][4]?><?php if($_GET['section']!=0){echo '/'.$rowbrandsubcat[0][5];}?>/<?php echo $rowimage[$i][6];?>')"></div>
                <?php }?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>



    </div><!-- #camera_wrap_3 -->

</div><!-- .fluid_container -->
```

Comment: I uploaded the page online: http://in2info.com/pamcov2/brands.php?section=1&scat=1

Comment: and the slider alone is in the following link: http://in2info.com/pamcov2/slide.php?section=1&scat=1