# jQuery camera slideshow not displaying content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a web page with the camera slider from pixedelic.com, when used as a single page the content is displayed correctly, but when including it with another blocks the slideshow stops displaying the content.

It has to display 12 tab in every slide representing different brand names logos; here is the slideshow link working alone: http://in2info.com/pamco/slide.php?section=1&scat=1 and this link is when included with other parts of the page: http://in2info.com/pamco/brands.php?section=1&scat=1

Thank you.

Comment: please give some code, and make sure to ask your question in a way it will stay valid for a long time (for example, the two links you posted, will most likely not work anymore in one year from now, i assume).

Comment: the code is available on this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863478/tabs-not-displayed-in-camera-slideshow-slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863478/tabs-not-displayed-in-camera-slideshow-slider)

Comment: You cannot expect people to dig through the source code of your page to find the relevant code. Besides the fact that if you're using server-side languages, such as PHP, we may not get all the required information to help. Post the relevant code if you want help.